# Subtract the date and list the days in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

There are two rows in the table created and modified. I need to subtract a modified - created and list the days(given in result table).

Table name : user

```
|-----|---------------------|---------------|
| id  |       created       |   modified    |
|-----|---------------------|---------------|
| 1   | 2013-04-12 17:49:26 |  2013-04-16   |
| 2   | 2013-04-12 20:20:25 |  2013-04-26   |
| 3   | 2013-04-12 12:24:23 |  2013-04-12   |
| 4   | 2013-04-18 19:03:47 |  2013-04-23   |
|-------------------------------------------|
```

I need the result like this given below..

```
|-----|----------------|
| id  |    days        |
|-----|----------------|
| 1   |     4          |
| 2   |     14         |
| 3   |     0          |
| 4   |     5          |
|----------------------|
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`DateDiff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function for this:

```
SELECT ID, Datediff (modified,created) AS days
FROM user
```

Output:

```
╔════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ DAYS ║
╠════╬══════╣
║  1 ║    4 ║
║  2 ║   14 ║
║  3 ║    0 ║
║  4 ║    5 ║
╚════╩══════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77777/2)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose both created and modified are datetime type:

```
SELECT id, DATEDIFF(modified, created) as days FROM result
```

Comment: you are missing one opening bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT id, Datediff(modified,created) as days FROM user
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use DateTime::diff in php to do this. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

You want to use DateTime class also.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

In mysql use DATEDIFF() function
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff